# How to bypass 1000 maximum lambda invocations from S3 Batch Operations?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda

We have a bucket with over 3 billion objects that we're trying to migrate to a new bucket.  This isn't a straight up copy because we need to add a prefix to the object key, so we made a lambda function to do this.  S3 Batch operations seems to cap out at 1k concurrent invocations even if we have multiple batch operations running in parallel. If I were to create N lambda functions that does the same work and spawn N number of batch jobs, will this create n * 1k invocations or am I stuck at 1k here?

I've making 1 lambda function and spawning multiple batch operations.  They are all stuck at 1k concurrent invocations.

Comment: AWS Lambda has a default limit of 1000 concurrent executions (regardless of how it is invoked). You can go to the Quotas section of your AWS management console and request an increase.